# How can I change the title of an ionic app

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, google-tag-manager

My App is connected withe the GTM (Google Tag Manager). I want to see all page views from the users, but i only see the Ionic App. the title in the index.html is static, but can i do this dynamic?

Comment: Use this plugin: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/firebase-analytics

Comment: how i get the datas from firebase to Google Analytics?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `app.component.ts` file import `Title` class from `@angular/platform-browser` and add it in the constructor. Then add the code mentioned below

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.router.events
      .pipe(filter((event) => event instanceof NavigationEnd))
      .subscribe((event: any) => {
        const title = event.url;
        this._title.setTitle(`${title}`);
      });
  }
```

This way, you will be able to change the title of your `index.html` file.